# Serve css files dynamically in raw node.js

Tags: css, node.js, serve

I can servre css files when the browser requests for it, which is like

```
var pathname = url.parse(req.url, true);
if(pathname=="style.css"){
    //read the css file and write in the response
}
```

but using this approach i will have to write a router for each css and js file I use. Is there any way to do them dynamically. I have figured out a way which works  but seems to be vaulnarable.

```
var reqArray = pathname.split("/");
if(req.Array[reqArray.length -1].indexOf(".css") !=-1 && fs.existsSync(pathname)){
fs.readFile("./"+pathname, function(err,data){
 //server the file
    }
}
```

is it okay, or there is any better suggestion. Please don't tell me to use express or any toher framework.

Comment: https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static

Comment: ohh! thanks it just solved my problem. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: the problem is it ends the response after serving static files, how do i use it with my other routers which serves dynamic files? @Ryan

Comment: You would handle all the rest of your routes first, and then if you’d normally return a 404, pass the request on to node-static instead.